# Rails não instala no CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos

Estou com um VPS com CentOS rodando, e não consigo sair deste erro:

```
[athos@athoscastro bin]$ gem install rails
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /home/athos/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/athos/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Estou com todas as dependencias instaladas, mas quando tento instalar algo com o gem ele acontece isso. Acontece o mesmo com o passenger.

Comment: Qual a versão do ruby e RubyGems?

Comment: @LúcioRubens `ruby 2.0.0p598` (tava com a 2.2.2 instalado, mas tentei reinstalar pelo yum e saiu isso, ambas dão erro) e 2.0.14 do rubygems

Comment: rode antes este comando: `sudo yum install -y gcc ruby-devel zlib-devel`